# Replace images in android

Tags: android

I'm new to android. I have an image in res/values/drawable-hdpi named ic_launcher i want to replace this image by another image stored in another directory of the same project. I want to replace by using the java code. so please help me to sort out this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use   `myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);` and call `myImageView.invalidate()` if the resource is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with:

imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgName);

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.YOURIMAGE);
```

// If incase your image would not change then add below line.

```
imageView.invalidate();
```